# Insert multiple json data into mysql database from postman using codeigniter api

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I am tring to insert multiple data in db using postman but only single data is insetred successfully ,when inserting multiple data getting 500 error.Please help me on how can i insert multiple data in db.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you.
PostMan raw data:

```
[{
    "total_sales":"14",
    "total_product":"21",
    "total_profit":"5099",
    "total_distributor":14,
    "total_ratail":40 },
    {
    "total_sales":14,
    "total_product":21,
    "total_profit":50,
    "total_distributors":14,
    "total_ratail":40 }
]
```

Below is my code:

```
   public function create()
    {
        $model = new AdminModel();
            print_r("total_sales");
            $data = array(
                'total_sales'=>$this->request->getVar('total_sales'),
                'total_product'=>$this->request->getVar('total_product'),
                'total_profit'=>$this->request->getVar('total_profit'),
                'total_distributors'=>$this->request->getVar('total_distributors'),
                'total_ratail'=>$this->request->getVar('total_ratail'),
            ); 
       
            $query = $model->where('id', $data['total_sales'])->find();

            if(count($query)>0){
                $model->update->where('id', $data['total_sales'])->find();
            }   
            else{
                $model->insert($data);
            }   

        //$model->insert($data);
        $response = [
            'status'   => 200,
            'error'    => null,
            'messages' => [
                'success' => 'Data Saved'
            ]
        ];
        return $this->respondCreated($response);
    }
```

Comment: Obviously the code is not made to insert more than 1 record at a time. Look into the error.log regarding the 500 error

Comment: Please read [`$builder->insertBatch()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-insertbatch)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an array of objects but the code is expecting only one object. That's why you are getting the error.

You have to modify your php code to accept an array and loop through them.